# Abstracting out queries to the Azure Table Storage using Expressions

Tags: c#, azure

I'm creating a class to perform CRUD functionality with Azure Table Storage.

I'm using generic types in this.

I have the following method, which i'm trying to pass in an expression to get used in the `TableQuery`, but am having some issues.

The line `TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>().Where<T>(criteria);` won't compile, and gives me the message

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>'
to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery<T>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I understand the message and know it's telling me i'm missing a cast, though I'm unsure how to code it correctly.

My full method is:

```
 public List<T> GetSome<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria) where T : ITableEntity, new()
 {

        TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>().Where<T>(criteria); // <---- This line isn't working

        List<T> results = table.ExecuteQuery<T>(query).ToList<T>();

        return results;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out - how i can pass in a lambda expression for Azure Table Storage to use.

I changed my method to the following:

```
 public List<T> GetSome<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria) where T : ITableEntity, new()
 {                        
    // table, in this case, is my `CloudTable` instance
    List<T> results = table.CreateQuery<T>().Where(criteria).ToList();

    return results;
 }
```

I can now pass in an expression. For example, to search against a `DynamicTableEntity` I can use:

```
 // my table storage class
 TableStorage ts = new TableStorage("ContactData");

 // search with expression
 List<DynamicTableEntity> results = ts.GetSome<DynamicTableEntity>(t => t.Properties["FirstName"].StringValue == "Darren");
```

If this is something you wouldn't/shouldn't do against an Azure Table Store, please do let me know.

In the meantime, this is how I have met the requirement.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for too. I also had difficulty writing code to translate an expression to a TableStorage query

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the value returned by the extension method [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.where%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) is of type [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX), but you're assigning to a variable of type `TableQuery<T>` and there is no implicitly valid type conversion between these types.

Comment: I understand that. Where i was struggling is how i can get it working. I figured I was using the wrong methods, though wasn't sure which ones i should be using in order to pass in a lambda.